# updated value in associative array when key match with another array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am trying to update the **array1** value when key match with **array2.** And **return whole array1 with updated value**

```
$array1 =array("subj1"=>"10","subj2"=>"20","subj3"=>"30","subj4"=>"40","subj5"=>"36","subj6"=>"85");
print_r($array1);
Array
(
    [subj1] => 10
    [subj2] => 20
    [subj3] => 30
    [subj4] => 40
    [subj5] => 36
    [subj6] => 85
)
$array2=array("subj1"=>"110","subj2"=>"130");
print_r($array2);
Array
(
    [subj1] => 110
    [subj2] => 130
)
```

below is my desired result.

```
Array
(
    [subj1] => 110
    [subj2] => 130
    [subj3] => 30
    [subj4] => 40
    [subj5] => 36
    [subj6] => 85
)
```

**How do I achieve this?**

Comment: print_r(array_merge($array1, $array2));

Comment: use php's array_merge: array_merge($array1, $array2);

Comment: @TuanDuong yup this is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_merge](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for that like this:

```
array_merge($array1, $array2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to get the desire output :

```
  <?php
$array1 =array("subj1"=>"10","subj2"=>"20","subj3"=>"30","subj4"=>"40","subj5"=>"36","subj6"=>"85");
print_r($array1);
echo "<br>";
$array2=array("subj1"=>"110","subj2"=>"130");
print_r($array2);
echo "<br>";
print_r(array_merge($array1, $array2)); 
?>
```